# Media Sharing on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, media-server

I want a Server 2008R2 (x64) to act as DNLA-Server. I remember I tried this with a Server 2008 about two years ago and this was only possible with some ugly hacks.

Is it on Server 2008R2 now possible to enable Windows MediaPlayer Media-Sharing by installing the desktop experience packet? Has someone already experience on this. Or is there another possibility to allow media sharing on a Server 2008R2 "the designated way"?

I remember that on Server 2008 the way was to install the old MediaConnect-Pacakge. But I hesitate to install such a component on a server. Anciently I installed VirtualServer with Vista and enabled the media server there in, but this seems to me somewhat overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read a lot on this when trying to set it up but I found it just did not work in Server 2008.  It appears to still be ugly hacks.  I believe MS want you to use Microsoft Home Server for this.  I had also tried to install the windows media services and after a lot of head scratching, trial and error and more I ended up just putting Windows 7 on the host as it was just a few clicks to get DNLA working.

I believe the only other options are to use something like PS3 media server.

http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/

It is a real shame they don't make this easy but I guess it is the split between home and enterprise.